# How to Register a Type from an Autofac app.config file

Tags: autofac, autofac-module

In the building of my container, I would like to feed one of these lines via the configuration file

```
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //NOTE: Depending on the PerformanceCategoryDefine in Configuration file
  // -will depend on which engine should be used -- choose one only
  //

  //builder.RegisterType<RemoteFxNetworkTransmitEngine>().As<IPerfCounterCategoryNameTransmitEngine>();

  //builder.RegisterType<TerminalServicesSessionTransmitEngine>().As<IPerfCounterCategoryNameTransmitEngine>();

  //---------------------------
```

Using the example from here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html#encapsulated-configuration

but it's rather limited, and not a complete example.  For some reason, I'm not able to locate the ConfigurationSettingsReader class as well.

I'm using Autofac version 4.1., as this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735992/using-modules-and-config-files-in-autofac) is now over 5 years old, I'm thinking it' no longer relevant.

Comment: The doc is pretty clear. Do you have the [Autofac.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Configuration/) package?

Comment: Yes, i also used the object browers to search the namespace, and couldnt find it!